# Split to take value in string in bigquery

Tags: split, google-bigquery

I want to split the value of `distinct_id` in this array in **BigQuery**.
This is in format String, how could I split to take it?

```sql
{'time': 1663062534, 'distinct_id': '0E0DC3C5-F945-448D-91CA-05284BB982DC', '$app_build_number': '175', '$app_version_string': '2.22.62', '$carrier': 'VinaPhone', '$city': 'Ho Chi Minh City', '$device_id': '0E0DC3C5-F945-448D-91CA-05284BB982DC', '$distinct_id_before_identity': '50566', '$had_persisted_distinct_id': 0, '$insert_id': '98914c9779432117', '$lib_version': '1.4.2', '$manufacturer': 'Apple', '$model': 'iPhone10,2', '$mp_api_endpoint': 'api.mixpanel.com', '$mp_api_timestamp_ms': 1663037334686, '$os': 'iOS', '$os_version': '15.6.1', '$radio': 'LTE', '$region': 'Ho Chi Minh', '$screen_height': 736, '$screen_width': 414, '$user_id': '50566', 'mp_country_code': 'VN', 'mp_lib': 'react-native', 'mp_processing_time_ms': 1663037334740, 'register': 0}
```

Comment: Not quite understanding the question. You want to _split_ the value? Pull it out of the current string, or split the 'distinct_id' by a character or..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the approach below:

```
with 
input as (
  select "{'time': 1663062534, 'distinct_id': '0E0DC3C5-F945-448D-91CA-05284BB982DC', '$app_build_number': '175', '$app_version_string': '2.22.62', '$carrier': 'VinaPhone', '$city': 'Ho Chi Minh City', '$device_id': '0E0DC3C5-F945-448D-91CA-05284BB982DC', '$distinct_id_before_identity': '50566', '$had_persisted_distinct_id': 0, '$insert_id': '98914c9779432117', '$lib_version': '1.4.2', '$manufacturer': 'Apple', '$model': 'iPhone10,2', '$mp_api_endpoint': 'api.mixpanel.com', '$mp_api_timestamp_ms': 1663037334686, '$os': 'iOS', '$os_version': '15.6.1', '$radio': 'LTE', '$region': 'Ho Chi Minh', '$screen_height': 736, '$screen_width': 414, '$user_id': '50566', 'mp_country_code': 'VN', 'mp_lib': 'react-native', 'mp_processing_time_ms': 1663037334740, 'register': 0}" as text)

select text, json_value(text,'$.distinct_id') as extract_distinct_id from input
```

Doc : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value

Comment: I have never seen this syntax is JS before. Looks a lot like linq query in C#

Comment: This is a SQL query for BigQuery. The input might not be a proper json string but the function does work here

Comment: I see my confusion. I'd be searching for the 'react' tag, and this question came up, so I thought it was JS related. Good thing I didn't try and answer haha